# The column 'PATIENT_ID' was specified multiple times for 'aa'

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a table using the query. But I get an error even I specified the exact alias to the columns.

```
SELECT
    * 
INTO
    call_drug 
FROM
    (SELECT
         P.PATIENT_ID, O.PATIENT_ID, P.MRNO,
         O.MRNO, P.OLDMRNO, P.PATIENTNAME, P.DOB, 
         P.REGISTRATIONDATE AS FIRSTVISITDATE,
         P.AGE, P.GENDERID, DO.NOOFDAYS, DO.QUANTITY,
         DO.EFFECTIVEDATE, DO.TOTAL, STARTDATE,
         O.ORDEREDDATE, DO.ENDDATE, DO.PHARAMACYORDERTYPE,
         DO.PRESCRIPTION_TYPE, DO.INSTRUCTION, DO.ACTIVE_DRUG_NAME,
         DO.ACTIVE_DRUG, DG.DRUG_GEN_NAME
     FROM
         HINAI_PATIENT P,
         HINAI_ORDERS O, 
         hinai_drugorder DO, 
         hinai_DRUGGENERICS DG,
         HINAI_GENERICDRUGMAPPING GM
     WHERE   
         P.MRNO = O.MRNO
         AND P.PATIENT_ID = O.PATIENT_ID
         AND O.ORDER_ID = DO.ORDERS_ID
         AND DO.DRUGID = GM.ITEMGENERICID
         AND DO.DRUGFORM = GM.DRUGFORM
         AND DG.DRUG_GEN_ID = GM.DRUGGENERICS
         AND DO.PHARAMACYORDERTYPE = 'PRESCRIPTION') aa
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: The table name is not part of the field name in the target table, so both "P.Patient_ID" and "O.Patient_ID" are really just "Patient_ID" as far as the CALL_DRUG table is concerned, and that's what it's complaining about.

Comment: Instead: `SELECT
         P.PATIENT_ID as p_patient_id, O.PATIENT_ID as o_patient_id` Or just omit one since it's just going to be the same value twice.

Comment: Jammy. Your inner code works fine. It generates a result set. Two of the columns in that result set HAVE THE SAME NAME... You need to add an alias to those columns or remove one of them from the subquery. Please look at the code sample I put in my comment and implement.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks for your support. I find the solution by your suggestion.